# About the proof of $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is isomorphic to $M_{n\times m}(F),$ given $\dim{V}=n,\dim{W}=m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

In the proof it just shows that $\large\Phi$ is onto, so why the part of one-to-one(injective) is omitted? And I'm taking an online course the teacher said: If $T:V\to W$ linear, and $V,W$ finite dimension then onto implies one-to-one. But as the second pic. theorem2.5 it says that it should be finite **and of equal** dimension, so which part of my understanding is wrong? Or finite dimension implies equal dimension in theorem 2.5?

[image: All LT is matrix 1]

--

[image: theorem 2.5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author says "... *there exists* a **unique** linear transformation $T: V \to W$..." in the proof.  "There exists" is surjectivity, "unique" is injectivity.  The quoted theorem by the author (Theorem 2.6 on page 72) gets the uniqueness for you.

Comment: Thank you so much...

Comment: To say $f: X \to Y$ is one-to-one means that for each $y \in Y$ we have that $f(x)=y$ has either zero or one solution in $x$.  Of course if $f$ is already known to be onto then $f$ is one-to-one if and only if $f(x)=y$ has a unique solution $x$ given any $y$.  This is the approach the author is taking.

Comment: May I ask an additional one: Is that the definition of $\Phi$ itself shows that it is one-to-one? And is this because of the theorem 2.6(, which states that given a basis of $V$ and assign each one a vector in $W$, there exists an unique linear $T:V\to W$)? Sorry I typed it wrong so this is a repost.

Comment: Yes, correct.  That theorem already states that $\Phi$ is one to one by uniqueness of basis representations.